# Trying to play YouTube video FullScreen in Android does not work

Tags: android, youtube

I am trying to play `YouTube` video directly in my app using the `API`. And I am able to successfully play the video, however, I need to play the video automatically in full screen, presently, I am able to go full screen on click of a button, and when I tried to do Automatically, I am getting errors. Here is the code to the Activity:

```
public class YouPlayer extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener,
        YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener {

    private static final int PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 9
            ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT
            : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT;

    private LinearLayout baseLayout;
    private YouTubePlayerView playerView;
    private YouTubePlayer player;
    private Button fullscreenButton;
    private CompoundButton checkbox;
    private View otherViews;

    private boolean fullscreen;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_player);
        baseLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player);
        fullscreenButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_button);
        checkbox = (CompoundButton) findViewById(R.id.landscape_fullscreen_checkbox);
        otherViews = findViewById(R.id.other_views);

        checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        // You can use your own button to switch to fullscreen too
        fullscreenButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        playerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        doLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        this.player = player;
        setControlsEnabled();
        // Specify that we want to handle fullscreen behavior ourselves.
        player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
        player.setOnFullscreenListener(this);
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo("9l7wiqEGrfc");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return playerView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        player.setFullscreen(!fullscreen);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        int controlFlags = player.getFullscreenControlFlags();
        if (isChecked) {

            setRequestedOrientation(PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION);
            controlFlags |= YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
            controlFlags &= ~YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
        }
        player.setFullscreenControlFlags(controlFlags);
    }

    private void doLayout() {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams playerParams =
                (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) playerView.getLayoutParams();
        if (fullscreen) {
            // When in fullscreen, the visibility of all other views than the player should be set to
            // GONE and the player should be laid out across the whole screen.
            playerParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            playerParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

            otherViews.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {

            otherViews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams otherViewsParams = otherViews.getLayoutParams();
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                playerParams.width = otherViewsParams.width = 0;
                playerParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                otherViewsParams.height = MATCH_PARENT;
                playerParams.weight = 1;
                baseLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            } else {
                playerParams.width = otherViewsParams.width = MATCH_PARENT;
                playerParams.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
                playerParams.weight = 0;
                otherViewsParams.height = 0;
                baseLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            }
            setControlsEnabled();
        }
    }

    private void setControlsEnabled() {
        checkbox.setEnabled(player != null
                && getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        fullscreenButton.setEnabled(player != null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        fullscreen = isFullscreen;
        doLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        doLayout();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_you_player, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();


        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/player"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/other_views"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:text="@string/fullscreen_tutorial"/>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/landscape_fullscreen_checkbox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/landscape_fullscreen"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/enter_fullscreen"/>

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

So my question is how to automatically play video in full screen as soon as the Activity is launched? Thanks,